# White space above action bar on .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, xaml, maui

I have an fresh app made with .NET MAUI that I'm struggling with somethiung strange, there's an extra white space above my action bar:

[image]

I can't figure what it is, did anyone know how to remove it?
Here's my layouts (I don't have any code in this app yet)

App.xaml

```
    <Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxxxxx"
             x:Class="xxxxx.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell
    x:Class="equinovet_2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxxxx.Pages"
    FlyoutBackground="{StaticResource gradientxxxxx}"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    <Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".75*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Padding="0,50,0,50"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        MaximumHeightRequest="40"
                        Source="ic_horse.png" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Padding="0,50,0,50"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        MaximumHeightRequest="30"
                        Source="logo.png" />
                    <Label
                        FontSize="16"
                        Text="Médico Veterinário"
                        TextColor="white" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>

    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.25*,.75*">
                <Image
                    Margin="15,15,15,15"
                    HeightRequest="25"
                    Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                    TextColor="white"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Meu Perfil"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_colaboradores.png"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Início"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_home.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Procedimentos"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_procedimentos.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Animais"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_animais.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Proprietários"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_colaboradores.png"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Controle Folicular"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_folicular.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Reprodução"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_reproducao.png"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Serviços"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_services.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Estoque"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_storage.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Fornecedores"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_fornecedores.png"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Financeiro"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_financeiro.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Relatórios Financeiros"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_chart.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Relatórios de Serviços"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_folicular.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Agenda"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_calendar.png"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Catálogo de Exames"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_exames.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Colaboradores"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_colaboradores.png"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Configurações"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_config.png"
            Route="MainPage" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="Sincronização"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            FlyoutIcon="ic_sync.png"
            Route="MainPage" />

    </FlyoutItem>


</Shell>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="xxxxx.Pages.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="Início"
    Background="gray">
    <Label Text="teste" />
</ContentPage>
```

Styles.xaml (Pretty much .NET MAUI default, below is the only new things I added)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Shadow
        x:Key="shadow"
        Brush="black"
        Opacity="0.3"
        Radius="15"
        Offset="0,15" />

    <Style Class="FrameBorder" TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray300}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I don't know if anymore code are relevant, but to this screen, it's just these two...
I appreciate any help, I'm new to .NET MAUI, don't know much about it

Thanks

Comment: I used your Shell Xaml in my Emulator and I don't see any extra space. Can you try with a different Emulator and check if you're still seeing white space? I used Pixel 5 to test.

Comment: Just tested on a fresh Pixel 5 emulator, and still got the extra space, can't figure what is this

Comment: I created the project based on your code, there is no white space above action bar. Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example？For specific steps, you can refer to this link: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).